# Change RecyclerView data with Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am working on a project with TabLayout.I have 20 tabs. I use one RecyclerView Adapter and Fragment. When I click any tabs I want recyclerview and fragment to change data. How can I do that in TabLayout's getItem function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add an OnPageChangeListener on your ViewPager. You will be able to detect when you change your active tab.
I would suggest something like this :

```
private int lastPosition = -1;
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if(position != lastPosition){
        lastPosition = position;
        // refresh recyclerview and fragment
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Actually I have a method that fetchs data from JSON according to category name. I have 20 categories I mean. When I click any tabs I want to show user another category. How can I refresh Fragment and RV in Onpageselected method?

Comment: I mean how do I recal fragment in onpageselected?

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood your question then :/ I don't really think I can help you much as i'm very new to Android development. Can you maybe use something like this ? FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, newFragment).commit();

Comment: Why? Your sayings are correct but I am really stuck on this trouble. I dont know what I do. Thanks